# Excel VBA: What is the variable type for a description of range?

Tags: excel, vba

My code looks for the column numbers of columns with certain headers, sees how long the file is and generates ranges based on that. For example:

```
    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws1

    FinalColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    FinalRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 1 To FinalColumn
                   .Cells(1, j).Value = "FolderId" Then
                            FolderId_column = j
                    End If
     Next j
     Total_Folder_Column = FinalColumn + 1
     range_FolderId_Fixed = .Cells(2, FolderId_column).Address & ":" & .Cells(FinalRow,  FolderId_column).Address
     range_FolderId_Cell = .Cells(2,FolderId_column).Address(RowAbsolute:=False,ColumnAbsolute:=False)
     range_Total_Folder_Fixed = .Cells(2, Total_Folder_Column).Address & ":" & .Cells(FinalRow, Total_Folder_Column).Address

     .Range(range_Total_Folder_Fixed).Formula = "=SUMIF(" & range_FolderId_Fixed & "," & range_FolderId_Cell & "," & range_Total_Folder_Fixed & ")"

     End With
```

My question is that I don't know how to define the DIM of variables like range_FolderId_Cell.

Are these String or Range type or something else?

```
Dim range_FolderId_Fixed As ???
Dim range_FolderId_Cell As ???
```

I am guessing that

```
 Dim FinalRow As Long
```

Thanks.

Comment: Dim range_FolderId_Fixed As Range?

Comment: Dim range_FolderId_Fixed As String...!

Comment: @bamie9l I was hoping for a  "Dim ....Range ! "  :)

Comment: Ok there you go, @KazJaw provided the authority. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your situation you should use this variable declaration.

```
Dim range_FolderId_Fixed as String
```

Tip- if you don't know which variable type you should use you could always check it in this way:

```
'Delcare as variable
Dim range_FolderId_Fixed as Variant
' after you set the value in your code
range_FolderId_Fixed = ...
'check automatic assignment in this way
Debug.Print TypeName(range_FolderId_Fixed)
```

as a result you get `String` in your situation in Immediate window. Next you could back to your code and change `Variable` into `String`.

Comment: is Dim myvar As Variable different from Dim myvar As Variant ?

Comment: my mistake, should be `as Variant`- i've just improved my code.

Comment: I just ran it and I didn't see any messages from debug. Where will the messages appear?

Comment: Ok found it. Immediate Window. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Dim range_FolderId_Fixed as String